# FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder in Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following way to post a message via Android Facebook SDK

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(mActivity)
                .setApplicationName("My app")
                .setName("Hi All:")
                .setPicture("https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/27928_228440670639329_1320586523_n.jpg")
                .setDescription("I've just created a card, Check it out!")
                .setLink(shareLink)
                .build();
```

To be confused, on Facebook feed, there would an advertisement inserted. What's wrong with my code?
[image]

Comment: what is the value of shareLink?

Comment: @FlavorScape, shareLink is an ordinary linkage like: http://tinyurl.com/xxxxxx

Comment: I ask because maybe FB is blocking, or in reality your variable is bad or not a valid URL. You're sure its not null or something at that point?

Comment: @FlavorScape, i can open this linkage in facebook feed, so i'm sure the url is not bad.